# Laravel Controller Passing parameter to JasperReport Query

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to pass a parameter from my controller to jasper jrxml file but it doesn't work.

Here the controller will pass value 1  through a parameter id to the jrxml file. 
SampleController.php

```
<?php namespace report;

use View;
use JasperPHP\JasperPHP; //cossou


class SampleController extends \BaseController {
public function generate(){
    $jasper = new JasperPHP();
    $filename = 'report1';

    $jasper->process(
        app_path() . '/views/report/test/'.$filename.'.jasper',
        public_path(). '/report/test/'.$filename,
        array("pdf"),
        array('id'=> 1)->execute();

    return View::make('report.index',
        array('report_title'=>'SAMPLE REPORT', 
        'pdf' => 'test/'.$filename.'.pdf' ));
   }
}
```

report1.jrxml

```
SELECT dbo.cfg_district.code, dbo.cfg_district.name, dbo.cfg_district.state_name, 
dbo.cfg_district.state_code, dbo.cfg_district.i FROM dbo.cfg_district 
WHERE dbo.cfg_district.id =$P{id}
```

If I use $P{id} alone and put it on design, it does work but whenever I add it to the query, it does not work. I've tried changing it to $P!{id}, it is still the same.

I was hoping it could show a result in the dynamic table.

Any help is much welcome. Thank you!